# How to fix "Android Studio recent project list goes empty and want to retrieve back"

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Because of the battery drain. My laptop is suddenly shutdown and as I have restarted and start Android studio I cannot see any recent project list on the start screen. Android studio start screen looks as I have started android studio for the first time. I have almost more than 150+ project list in the recent project. (List of 4+ years of the android project)

Can someone help me to retrieve this list?

I have already checked "recentProjects.xml" file from this location "\Users\Username.AndroidStudio3.4\config\options\" but I have found "recentProjects.xml" file with the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If your file was deleted due to sudden shutdown but if your file was deleted then you can try to recover it with the help of recovery softwares like recuva

[Checkout this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2216/restore-accidentally-deleted-files-with-recuva/amp/)

Comment: I have already tried this type of software to recover the file but it wont help.

Comment: then the android studio might have modified that file.. I guess